# Why does my computer keep freezing?

Tags: 10.10, freeze

My computer is presenting some weird behaviour, and I don't know what to try next to work out what's going wrong.

First the behaviour. The computer occasionally freezes. I can move the mouse, and the cursor changes (e.g., to a movement arrow, hand, text cursor etc). But nothing else on the screen moves. Counters don't count, windows don't move, clicks do nothing. Waiting doesn't help - it doesn't wake back up.

I can CTRL-ALT-F5 to an alternative terminal session and see what's running. Nothing seems to be maxing out any resources.

As far as I can tell, it's not tied to any one single application. I've tried to use the computer with different apps and it seems to still happen whatever I stop running, short of killing of Xorg and nautilus, obviously.

I've tried the xorg-edgers repo. No improvement. I've disabled compiz (I think) - no improvement. I've looked in a few log files but couldn't see anything that would indicate where the problem is (though I might well have been looking in the wrong place).

My next options are to reinstall and/or start swapping out hardware. But before I do that, can anyone tell me what can cause crashes like this, where the mouse can move but nothing else does? Or can anyone tell me which logs files I should be checking? Is there anything else I can try, to diagnose the problem? Is it likely to be a hardware issue?

The computer is a vanilla Dell XPS 8300 - details at http://dell.com/uk/p/xps-8300 - except for the graphics card, which is an ATI Radeon X1300 Pro.

Comment: What hardware are we dealing with?

Comment: It's a vanilla Dell XPS 8300 - details at http://www.dell.com/uk/p/xps-8300 - except for the graphics card, which is an ATI Radeon X1300 Pro.

Comment: try the following logs: /var/log/dmesg and /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Comment: @DaveChild: Can you add those details directly to your question?

Comment: Looks like the same bug as I am experiencing: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/775060 Currently, I am not sure what is the cause, but I suspect that it is a combination of issues, where compiz is a part of the issue.

Comment: @Roland Taylor: Done.

Comment: @Dirk: Thanks - will grab those next time it crashes.

Comment: @nickguletskii: Thanks for the link. I've subscribed to the bug and will try and add to the information there when it crashes again. Given that it appears to be a compiz issue, or at least compiz related, I'll try disabling compiz to see if that makes any difference.